# How come I don't print and image

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my code:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.cbssports.com/nba/draft/mock-draft').read())

rows = soup.findAll("table", attrs = {'class': 'data borderTop'})[0].tbody.findAll("tr")[2:]

for row in rows:
    fields = row.findAll("td")
    if len(fields) >= 3:
        anchor = row.findAll("td")[1].find("a")
        if anchor:
            print anchor
```

Instead of printing out an image, it gives me where the image is in the page source. Any reasons as to why?

Comment: What do you mean by "printing out an image"  and by "gives me where the image is in the page source" ?

Answer (score 0):

According to BeautifulSoup documentation, soup.findAll returns a list of tags or NavigableStrings.
So you have to use specific methods such as content().

Visit http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html at "Navigating the Parse Tree" subtitle to find what you need in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the team logo thumbnails?

```
import urllib2
import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.cbssports.com/nba/draft/mock-draft'
txt = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
bs = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(txt)

# get the main table
t = bs.findAll('table', attrs={'class': 'data borderTop'})[0]

# get the thumbnail urls
imgs = [im["src"] for im in t.findAll('img')] if "logos" in im["src"]]
```

`imgs` now looks like

```
[[u'http://sports.cbsimg.net/images/nba/logos/30x30/NO.png',
 u'http://sports.cbsimg.net/images/nba/logos/30x30/CHA.png',
 u'http://sports.cbsimg.net/images/nba/logos/30x30/WAS.png',
 u'http://sports.cbsimg.net/images/nba/logos/30x30/CLE.png',
```

etc. These are the file locations for each logo, which is all the HTML actually contains; if you want the actual pictures, you have to get each one separately.

---

The list contains duplicate references to each logo; the quickest way to remove duplicates is

```
imgs = list(set(imgs))
```

Alternatively, the list does not include every team; if you had a full list of team name contractions, you could build the logo-url list directly.

Also, looking at the site, each 30x30 logo has a corresponding 90x90 logo which you might prefer - much larger and clearer. If so,

```
imgs = [im.replace('30x30', '90x90') for im in imgs]
```

`imgs` now looks like

```
[u'http://sports.cbsimg.net/images/nba/logos/90x90/BOS.png',
 u'http://sports.cbsimg.net/images/nba/logos/90x90/CHA.png',
 u'http://sports.cbsimg.net/images/nba/logos/90x90/CLE.png',
 u'http://sports.cbsimg.net/images/nba/logos/90x90/DAL.png',
```

etc.

---

Now, for each url, we download the image and save it:

```
import os

savedir = 'c:\\my documents\\logos'  # assumes this dir actually exists!
for im in imgs:
    fname = im.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
    fname = os.path.join(savedir, fname)
    with open(fname, 'wb') as outf:
        outf.write(urllib2.urlopen(im).read())
```

and you have your logos.